# Browser updates view for incoming data not one-by-one

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

For an industrial project, I'm testing the performance of websockets.

My server-side code sends 10000 websocket-events in a loop with randomly generated data. The client displays these data-packets in a table.

Problem is: the client does not display **each** dataset after receiving it. Instead of that the client updates the view after receiving **all** datasets.

I use Node.js with socket.io server-side.

First: Generating random data

```
var data = [];

for(var i = 0; i<10000; i++){
    data[i] = 
    {
        nr: i,
        x: Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 ),
        y: Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 )
    };
}
```

Second: Sending it sequentially

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    socket.emit('dataset', data[i]);
}
```

Third: Client-side adding tr/td-Elements to a table

```
var socket = io.connect('...');
var table= $('...');

socket.on('dataset', function (data) {
    var tr = $('<tr/>').appendTo(table);
    var nr = $('<td/>')
        .text(data.nr)
        .appendTo(tr);
    var x = $('<td/>')
        .text(data.x)
        .appendTo(tr);
    var y = $('<td/>')
        .text(data.y)
        .appendTo(tr);
});
```

The browser does not update the table every time a socket-packet arrives. Instead it waits for the loop to end. Server-side, the events are being sent verifiable one by one.

My guess was that using a table is the reason, but using a (ugly) innerHTML-function had the same effect.

You can view that live on http://daniel-betz.de:1338/. It needs a few seconds to display the datasets ('cause it doesn't display them one by one - but that's what I want). Please ignore the german wording.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're emitting them instantly, which is pretty much sending them all at once and locking up the browser.

Comment: So do you suggest slowing them down (with setTimeout)? The speed was one argument for the sockets...

Comment: You don't have to, but when you're trying to update your UI 10,000 times, it's bound to lag/hang.